# How to use factories during the config phase (angular)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my project I have a couple of `provider`s which I initialise during startup

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .config((barFooProvider, ....) => {
        barFooProvider.setAPIPath = '/a/b/c';
        ...
    });
```

As you can see I define an api-path here which is a string. But how can I set for example a factory ? Or is the only way to define the name of the service and later on use the $injector ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `$inject` property annotation ([docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di)) on the `$get` method of your provider:

```
myApp.provider('test', function() {

    this.setFactoryName = function(name) {
        this.$get.$inject = [name];
    };

    this.$get = function(factory) {
        return { 
            getMessageFromFactory: function() {
                return factory.msg;
            }
        };
    };

    // set default value
    this.setFactoryName('myFactory1');

});
```

then configure it this way:

```
myApp.config(function(testProvider){
    testProvider.setFactoryName('myFactory2');
});
```

This way the required factory will be injected to the `$get` method of your provider upon service instantiation.

Comment: This is a nice solution. I already use the $injector like this: `this.$get = function($injector) { ... }`. In my case the dependencies are optional, meaning that you can set none or a couple of services. As far as I know this cannot be done with you solution, is that true?

Comment: @JeanlucaScaljeri, yes, I guess so.

Answer (score 0):

You just can use Providers in Config Phase 
In other words Providers are Configurable in AngularJs
May be this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666048/angularjs-service-vs-provider-vs-factory) would be helpfull

Answer (score 0):

providers are the only services that can be used in config phase!

```
app.provider('test', function() {

  // set default path
  var APIPath = 'a/b/c';

  function setAPIPath(path) {
       APIPath =  path;
  }

});


angular.module('app', []).config(function(testProvider) {
  // set path during config
  testProvider.setAPIPath('x/v/b');
});
```